# How to use .each() in this case?

Tags: jquery

My goal with this code is to get the `.post-body .separator img` `alt` attribute and assign it on `<div class="post-body-image-description">`. I'm not sure, but I think I should use `.each()` somewhere in this jQuery code below to avoid that only the first `.post-body .separator img` `alt` attribute be assigned to all `.post-body-image-description`. But where and how should I insert this `.each()`?

**HTML markup**

```
<div class="post-body">
<div class="separator">
<a href="https://www.example.com">
<img src="https://www.example.com/image-01.png" alt="Alternative text example 1"/>
</a>
<div class="post-body-image-description"></div>
</div>

<div class="separator">
<a href="https://www.example.com">
<img src="https://www.example.com/image-02.png" alt="Alternative text example 2"/>
</a>
<div class="post-body-image-description"></div>
</div>

<div class="separator">
<a href="https://www.example.com">
<img src="https://www.example.com/image-03.png" alt="Alternative text example 3"/>
</a>
<div class="post-body-image-description"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".post-body .post-body-image-description").text(function() {
   return $('.post-body .separator a img').attr("alt");
});
```

Comment: Do you want to get all of the matching `alt` tags? Maybe you mean `map()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to use .each then this is how I would do it.

Good luck.

```js
$(".post-body .separator").each(function() {

  // Get the alt text for each.
  var altAtt = $(this).find("img").attr("alt"); 

  // Insert the alt text into each description div.
  $(this).find(".post-body-image-description").text(altAtt); 
  
  // Check if there is a description box class and if not apply a css format to the .separator
  // You can check if it exists or not by using .length 
  if($(this).find(".post-body-image-description").length){
    $(this).addClass("someExtraFormat");
  }
  
  // If you wanted to add a format if there is no .post-body-image-description then you can check for 
  // a length of 0 like this:
  if($(this).find(".post-body-image-description").length == 0){
    $(this).addClass("someExtraFormatMissing");
  }
  

});
```

```css
.separator {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}

.post-body-image-description {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.someExtraFormat {
  background: green;
}

.someExtraFormatMissing {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="post-body">
  <div class="separator">
    <a href="https://www.example.com">
      <img src="https://www.example.com/image-01.png" alt="Alternative text example 1" />
    </a>
    <div class="post-body-image-description"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="separator">
    <a href="https://www.example.com">
      <img src="https://www.example.com/image-02.png" alt="Alternative text example 2" />
    </a>
    <div class="post-body-image-description"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="separator">
    <a href="https://www.example.com">
      <img src="https://www.example.com/image-03.png" alt="Alternative text example 3" />
    </a>
    <div class="post-body-image-description"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="separator">
    <a href="https://www.example.com">
      <img src="https://www.example.com/image-03.png" alt="Alternative text example 4" />
    </a>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I really liked your solution. Some of these `.separator` will not have the `.post-body-image-description` element. Is there a way to apply CSS styles specific to those `.separator` that will have the `.post-body-image-description` element?

Comment: If i understand your question, then if you want to add a format to the .separator if there IS a .post-body-image-description then you can do like I have added onto the above answer by using an if statement and checking if the class exist or not and adding a class from there.

Answer (score 1):

Using `text(function)` will loop over each selector. You just need to get the `alt` that is within the same `separator` container.

Use `closest()` to go up to the parent container and `find()` to look within that container for what you need

```js
$(".post-body .post-body-image-description").text(function() {
   return $(this).closest('.separator').find('a img').attr("alt");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-body">
  <div class="separator">
    <a href="https://www.example.com">
      <img src="https://www.example.com/image-01.png" alt="Alternative text example 1" />
    </a>
    <div class="post-body-image-description"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="separator">
    <a href="https://www.example.com">
      <img src="https://www.example.com/image-02.png" alt="Alternative text example 2" />
    </a>
    <div class="post-body-image-description"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="separator">
    <a href="https://www.example.com">
      <img src="https://www.example.com/image-03.png" alt="Alternative text example 3" />
    </a>
    <div class="post-body-image-description"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```